# Python: json.decoder.JSONDecodeError

Tags: python, python-3.x

I want to get a json response from server
Here is my code:

```
import requests
from requests_ntlm import HttpNtlmAuth

r = requests.get('http://helpbook.com/Home/UserInfo?empId=00458974',
auth=HttpNtlmAuth('domain\\login','password'))
print(r.json())
```

But each time I get the error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\user\Desktop\SM\PYTHON_SCRIPTS\Send json query\iso.py", line 6, in <module>
    print(r.json())
  File "C:\Program Files\Python36\lib\site-packages\requests\models.py", line 894, in json
    return complexjson.loads(self.text, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Program Files\Python36\lib\json\__init__.py", line 354, in loads
    return _default_decoder.decode(s)
  File "C:\Program Files\Python36\lib\json\decoder.py", line 339, in decode
    obj, end = self.raw_decode(s, idx=_w(s, 0).end())
  File "C:\Program Files\Python36\lib\json\decoder.py", line 357, in raw_decode
    raise JSONDecodeError("Expecting value", s, err.value) from None
json.decoder.JSONDecodeError: Expecting value: line 1 column 1 (char 0)
```

How to fix it?

Comment: What is content of `r.text()`?

Comment: the url you provided gives an error page. which is definitely not a valid json.

Comment: Use postman or other tool to check if the json is a valid one, or test your code with a hardcoded json to narrow down the issue

Answer (score 1):

I do not have enough reputation to post a comment.

`requests` cannot decode the JSON response, because there is no JSON response. You should check the return code first:

```
import requests
from requests_ntlm import HttpNtlmAuth

r = requests.get('http://helpbook.com/Home/UserInfo?empId=00458974',
                 auth=HttpNtlmAuth('domain\login', 'password'))

if r.status_code == 200:
    print(r.json())
else:
    print("Request failed: {} - {}".format(r.status_code, r.reason))
```

And you would get the result:
`Request failed: 404 - Not Found`

With that information, you can debug you HTTP API and check why you receive 404 error in the first place.

Comment: That means you have an authentication problem (correct username, password?). I always get `404` or `Page Not Found` when trying to use that URL, therefore I cannot try.